# Page load bootstrap collapse

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cookies, laravel

I have a unique issue. I am using Twitter bootstraps accordion collapse. All the collapse items are being pulled from my database in a loop. Inside each panel-collapse there are links which navigate to certain page etc.

To collapse each panel twitter bootstrap uses `in`. Each panel has an id which I generate inside my loop (it's how the accordion works). Lets say I access one of these links directly from address bar, in this case accordion does not know which links belong to which `.panel-body` and thus does not `collapse in` it will just load as normal

How do I go about telling accordion which `panel-body` to collapse `in` when accessing a link directly from address bar?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" >
    <a href="#" data-filter="*" class="list-group-item current">All Articles</a></li>
    @foreach($press_nav as $value)
      <div class="list-group panel">

        <a data-toggle="collapse" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#accordion" href="#{{ $value->id }}" data-filter=".{{ $value->category }}">

        <span class="badge pull-right">{{ $value->counter }}</span>
            {{ $value->category }}
        </a>

        <div id="{{ $value->id }}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            @foreach(explode(',', $value->category) as $category)
              <a data-pjax href="{{ URL::route('find-category', array('category' => $category)) }}">
                {{ $category }}
              </a><br><!--break-->
            @endforeach
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
```

NOTE: I am using Laravel, so I was thinking I could use a cookie and set the value `in` and then once navigated to a link, the cookie can inject that value to the class, however I would not know how to go about it.

Comment: want you open a "collapse" from a link?

Comment: sort of, this might be a solution, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the collapse Methods when press the link

### Methods

*.collapse(options)*

> Activates your content as a collapsible element. Accepts an optional options object.

```
$('#myCollapsible').collapse('show'/'hide'/'toggle');
```

[Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

Comment: I have looked into the method because it is a PHP generate accordion these methods don't work.

Comment: it works it works, I also generate collapse from php and then add an event. after generating the collapse, add a <script> </ script> and put inside the code for the event :)

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you do it? I must be missing something.